# Access 2007 form: event AFTER undo

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, keyevent

I have a form in Access 2007, which has an "update" routine, that enables or disables certain textboxes based on values in other fields (textboxes, checkboxes, comboboxes). The regular operation of that routine works well.

Now I found that pressing ESC calls the undo function, that restores the original values in all fields. But this undo does not call the events on those fields, so the form is in a wrong state, where textboxes are disabled/enabled although they shouldn't.

I also found that there is an undo-event, but that is useless for me because it is called before undo. I need an event after undo. What can I do here to update the fields when ESC is pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, like many times before I have an idea for a solution after postion the question.

The solution here is enabling KeyPreview on the form and using the KeyUp event. The undo is called on KeyDown, so when KeyUp is raised, the form already has the restored values again and the update routine works.

Answer (score 3):

I like this solution more, because it works not only on the "ESC"-Key:

```
private Sub form_Undo(cancel as integer)

  afterUndo = true

  TimerInterval = 1

end Sub

private Sub Form_Timer()

  if afterUndo then

    'do something after the Undo-Event

  end if

  TimerInterval = 0

end Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this problem is to use each control's `OldValue` property.  Through experimentation, I've found that the three different value properties of controls come into play in different situations:

- **`Control.Value`** or simply **`Control`**

  - The control's current value most of the time
  - When the control has focus, it is the value the control had before gaining focus
  - During a `Form.Undo` event, it is the value the control prior to the Undo
  - Relevant during the `Control.AfterUpdate` and `Control.Undo` events
- **`Control.Text`**

  - The control's value while it has focus
  - Relevant during events that occur as the user types, such as `Control.Change`, `Control.KeyUp`, `Control.KeyDown`
- **`Control.OldValue`**

  - The value the control had when the current record was first opened
  - Also the value that a form-level Undo will reset the control to
  - Relevant during the `Form.Undo` event

The timer-based answer to this question is my go-to solution, but if you're already handling events as the user types (e.g., for live validation), then code like this can be sensible:

```
Private Sub LastName_Change()
    ValidateLastName SourceProperty:="Text"
End Sub

Private Sub LastName_Undo(Cancel As Integer)
    ValidateLastName SourceProperty:="Value"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Undo(Cancel As Integer)
    ValidateLastName SourceProperty:="OldValue"
End Sub

Private Sub ValidateLastName(SourceProperty As Variant)
    Dim LastName As String
    Select Case SourceProperty
        Case "LastName"
            LastName = Nz(Me.LastName.Text, "")
        Case "Value"
            LastName = Nz(Me.LastName.Value, "")
        Case "OldValue"
            LastName = Nz(Me.LastName.OldValue, "")
        Case Else
            Debug.Print "Invalid case in ValidateLastName"
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    ' <Do something to validate LastName>
End Sub
```

Note that this method does not get you access to the post-Form-Undo value of `Control.Column(x)` of combo/list boxes.  You can get it by using `DLOOKUP` on `Control.OldValue`, but you're probably better off just using the timer-based solution instead.